# How to ensure that I/O requests have returned to a normal rate?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, io

On [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) I am using a `t2.small` [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance as a VPS serving a few websites on a LAMP (PHP) stack. I was just hit with a bill which almost triples my usual bill. I see that my **I/O requests usage was extraordinarily high**. I logged into the server and noticed that the disk was full. I've removed a bunch of non-critical files and logs and the disk (EBS) is now at <60% capacity, but I'd like to check two things.

1. How can I tell if the high number of I/O requests was due to the disk filling up?
2. How can I tell if I'm still burning through I/O requests?

I did not have the AWS-specific [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) monitoring service enabled, so I probably won't get an answer to #1, but any advice would be appreciated.

Regarding #2, I used the two methods mentioned in [this blog post](http://www.ghidinelli.com/2009/05/26/estimating-io-requests-ec2-ebs-costs) to determine my I/O rate, and it seems that it is very, very high. Here are some stats from the server:

```
$ iostat
Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (dysphoria)     2015-10-08      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.74    0.01    0.69   16.83    0.43   79.30

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
xvda            170.08     10039.29        32.52  843300857    2731428
xvdf              0.01         0.02         0.00       1308          0

$ cat /proc/diskstats
   1       0 ram0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       1 ram1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       2 ram2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       3 ram3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       4 ram4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       5 ram5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       6 ram6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       7 ram7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       8 ram8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1       9 ram9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1      10 ram10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1      11 ram11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1      12 ram12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1      13 ram13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1      14 ram14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1      15 ram15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       0 loop0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       1 loop1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       2 loop2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       3 loop3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       4 loop4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       5 loop5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       6 loop6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   7       7 loop7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 202       0 xvda 14198708 1225 1686588426 26715600 87579 51756 5461696 11290600 0 16654328 38003076
 202       1 xvda1 14198527 1203 1686586802 26715376 87579 51756 5461696 11290600 0 16654236 38002848
 202      80 xvdf 447 6 2616 288 0 0 0 0 0 288 288

$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2000       1910         89          6          6       1216
-/+ buffers/cache:        688       1312
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Though the above information was taken shortly after boot, the `iostat` report shows an initial TPS in the 50-80 range even after the system has been running for several hours. The server is serving about 20 sites, only three of which get more than a few hits per day. Those get on the order of a few hundred visitors per day. **The server and sites have remained in this configuration for years without issue.** Only recently has the I/O begun to spike, with no corresponding change in code, server configuration, or website load.

*Note that this question was originally asked on [the Amazon Web Services Official Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=217448&tstart=50) however nobody seemed to have been able to help there. Perhaps the question is too general for that forum.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is important information in the iostat man page that, if not understood can lead to a misunderstanding of the data presented.

> The first report generated by the iostat command provides statistics concerning the time since the system was booted. Each subsequent report covers the time since the previous report. All statistics are reported each time the iostat command is run.

So, your simple iostat above is reporting values collected since the system was started.

It is more normal to run iostst with an interval and discard the first set  of statistics e.g.

```
iostat 5
```

this will report the relevant statistics every 5 seconds.

Once you are collecting the correct data you will be able to understand the situation better.

---

Take a look at the [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/index.php) command. In particular running it with privilege and selecting `d` will enable disk io statistics per thread.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand that the first report is for the period from system boot until now. That report shows a TPS of 170 in the OP! I have since noticed that the initial TPS is very high after the system boots, however even after the system has been running for several hours the TPS will be in the 50-80 range. That is very high for a webserver that serves a few hundred hits per day, especially when it's not running a framework such as Wordpress or Drupal.

Comment: There is information in your comment that it would have been useful to put in your question. See my update.

Comment: Thank you, in fact I already did add that info to the question after I made the comment! I am experimenting with `atop` and `iotop` now, thank you!